# Is there a faster method to update a new column from another column but from a previous row?

Tags: sql-server, performance

My stored procedure is taking too long just to update one column with a value from another column but from a value of a previous row (ordered by an INT and secondly a STR)

The code I'm using:

```
DECLARE @ITERg INT;
SET @ITERg = 1

WHILE @ITERg < 6131
BEGIN
    UPDATE Avg14RSI 
    SET Avg14GreenP = (SELECT TOP 1 Avg14Green 
                       FROM Avg14RSI a 
                       WHERE IDn = @ITERg AND a.IntDate < Avg14RSI.IntDate 
                       ORDER BY a.IDn, a.Ticker, a.IntDate DESC) 
    WHERE IDn = @ITERg

    SET @ITERg = @ITERg + 1
END;
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? SQL Server 2014 introduces the `lead` and `lag` functions which are tailor made for this sort problem.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 not 2014.

Comment: You are right, the program name is Microsoft SQL Server 2014, but when I go to versions it says: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.2269.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.17905
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.34209
Operating System      6.3.9600

Comment: Thanks for the info, it worked much better with the `lag` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, it looks like you really do have SQL Server 2014. Confusingly, the first SQL Server 2014 release is version number 12.0.2000.8 (SP1 is 12.whatever), which is why you're seeing the 12.* versions for SSMS and the analysis services. If you're at all unsure, just do a `SELECT @@VERSION` and you'll get the full information about SQL Server itself.

Even if you have SQL Server 2012 you're OK because Martin Smith is correct that `LAG` and `LEAD` were introduced in SQL Server 2012.

`LAG` lets you gather values from a prior row (`LEAD` gets values from the following row). Here's a quick demo that lists of employees with their salaries, and it includes the salary that's nearest theirs but less (for example Masood makes 72,000 and Jen, who's right behind, makes 68,000):

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
  Name VARCHAR(20),
  Salary NUMERIC(10,2));
GO
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES
 ('Fred', 80000),
 ('Manaa', 65000),
 ('Ulrika', 90000),
 ('Masood', 72000),
 ('Jen', 68000);

SELECT
  Name,
  Salary,
  LAG(Salary) OVER (ORDER BY Salary) AS PriorSalary
FROM Employees
ORDER BY Name;

Name   Salary   PriorSalary
------ -------- -----------
Fred   80000.00 72000.00
Jen    68000.00 65000.00
Manaa  65000.00 NULL
Masood 72000.00 68000.00
Ulrika 90000.00 80000.00
```

So you can see that the row for Jen includes Manaa's salary, the row for Masood includes Jen's salary, etc. There's no salary lower than Manaa's so that row shows NULL for the prior salary.

Getting back to your data, you should be able to get a list of ID's with prior `Avg14Green` values within the `ID` with this query (I'll try to explain the `PARTITION` after the query):

```
SELECT
  IDn,
  LAG(Avg14Green) OVER (
    PARTITION BY IDn
    ORDER BY Ticker, IntDate DESC) AS PriorAvg14Green
FROM Avg14RSI;
```

The `PARTITION` says to get the prior `Avg14Green` when ordering by ticker and date descending, but only do so for other rows that have the same `IDn` value.

At any rate, try the query, and if it has the values you're looking for you can use it for a one-shot `UPDATE` instead of processing one `IDn` at a time; it's almost guaranteed to be faster:

```
UPDATE Avg14RSI
SET Avg14GreenP = pr.PriorAvg14Green
FROM Avg14RSI
JOIN (
  SELECT
    IDn,
    LAG(Avg14Green) OVER (
      PARTITION BY IDn
      ORDER BY Ticker, IntDate DESC) AS PriorAvg14Green
  FROM Avg14RSI
) pr ON Avg14RSI.IDn = pr.IDn;
```

Remember that the earliest row by `Ticker, IntDate DESC` will have `NULL` for `PriorAvg14Green`. I'm having a bit of a brain fart here and can't figure out what your existing code will do in this situation, so in case you don't want to update the first row for each `IDn` just add a `WHERE` clause to the above query to omit null `pr.PriorAvg14Green` values:

```
... the query above, plus
WHERE pr.Avg14Green IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That was really helpful!!, thanks a lot! Just saw it after I post my comment lol. ´lead´ and ´lag´ are saving me tons of time! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome Luciano! I saw your comment after I posted my answer and it made my day - from a short suggestion that you look at `LAG` and `LEAD` it looks like you figured it out by yourself, which is *awesome beyond belief* - very nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the `lag` function to be very useful:

```
UPDATE  UpdateTarget
SET Avg14GreenP = Displaced
FROM (SELECT a.Avg14GreenP, LAG(a.Avg14Green) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Ticker
ORDER BY a.[Date]) AS Displaced
FROM Avg14RSI a) AS UpdateTarget;
```